# Excel file get corrupted while downloading from server using java

Tags: java

I have written a code for downloading an excel file. File content derived from database. Code working on local machine but when deployed on server. Excel file getting currupted while downloading. I am unable to find the problem in my code. Please help me to get rid of this problem. First method to export the excel and second method for writing contents in excelsheet. And second methos is called by first method.

```
public static void doGetExportException(String sheetId, ResourceRequest resourceRequest, ResourceResponse resourceResponse) throws ServletException, IOException 
{


    HttpServletResponse response = PortalUtil.getHttpServletResponse(resourceResponse);
    try 
    {
        long maxSheetId = Long.parseLong(sheetId);
        System.out.println("maxSheetId="+maxSheetId);
        List<Customer_Exception> lstCustomer_Exceptions =UploadExcelUtil.getCustomerExceptions(maxSheetId);

        XSSFWorkbook outPutSheet= writeExcelsheet(lstCustomer_Exceptions);  

        ByteArrayOutputStream outByteStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        outPutSheet.write(outByteStream);
        byte [] outArray = outByteStream.toByteArray();

        String fileName = "Download_"+new Date(new java.util.Date().getTime())+".xlsx";
        response.setContentType("application/ms-excel; charset=UTF-8"); 
        response.setContentLength(outArray.length);
        response.setHeader("Expires:", "0"); 
        response.addHeader(HttpHeaders.CACHE_CONTROL, "max-age=3600, must-revalidate");
        response.addHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename="+fileName);
        response.addHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_ENCODING, "Binary");
        OutputStream outStream = response.getOutputStream();
        outStream.write(outArray);
        outStream.flush();
        outStream.close();   
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private static XSSFWorkbook writeExcelsheet(List<Customer_Exception> lstCustomer_Exceptions) {
    XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
    XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Exceptions");

    CellStyle styleHeader = workbook.createCellStyle();
    XSSFFont fontHeader = workbook.createFont();
    XSSFColor color = new XSSFColor(Color.BLACK);
    fontHeader.setColor(color);
    fontHeader.setBold(true);
    fontHeader.setFontHeight(13);
    styleHeader.setFont(fontHeader);
    sheet.createFreezePane(0, 1);
    CellStyle styleData = workbook.createCellStyle();
    XSSFFont fontData = workbook.createFont();
    fontData.setColor(color);
    fontData.setFontHeight(12);
    styleData.setFont(fontData);

    int rownum = 0;
    XSSFRow rowHeader = sheet.createRow(rownum++);
    List<String> lstCellHeaders =getCellHeaders();
    int cellnum = 0;
    for(String cellHeader:lstCellHeaders){
        XSSFCell cell = rowHeader.createCell(cellnum++);
        cell.setCellStyle(styleHeader);
        cell.setCellValue((String)cellHeader);

    }  



    for (Customer_Exception customer_Exception:lstCustomer_Exceptions) {
        List<String> lstCellValues =getCellValues(customer_Exception);
        XSSFRow rowData = sheet.createRow(rownum++);

        cellnum = 0;
        for(String cellValue:lstCellValues){
            XSSFCell cell = rowData.createCell(cellnum++);
            cell.setCellStyle(styleData);
            cell.setCellValue((String)cellValue);

        }  
    }
    return workbook;
}
```

Comment: Any exceptions occuring on the server / client side? Catching all exceptions is a bad practice, if you cannot handle/recover from an error during request processing you should rethrow it (possibly wrapped) or respond with an appropriate http code (e.g. 500).

Comment: I have added catch to find out the problems during downloading and want to show proper massege to user.

Comment: I had got the solution. I had removed the " response.addHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_ENCODING, "Binary");" then its working fine

Answer (score 0):

For .xlsx you should use ContentType of : "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet".
This fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

Even I was stuck with this issue for about 1 week. Finally, I resolved the issue and got an excel output without being corrupted by using the below code.

I did it as a maven project.

> Add the following dependency for Super CSV Core » 2.4.0 in your
>   pom.xml file

```
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.supercsv/super-csv -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.supercsv</groupId>
    <artifactId>super-csv</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Now use the below code for your controller class

> CSVFileDownloadController.java

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.supercsv.io.CsvBeanWriter;
import org.supercsv.io.ICsvBeanWriter;
import org.supercsv.prefs.CsvPreference;

import com.rapidvalue.master.employee.vo.Book;

@Controller
public class CSVFileDownloadController {
      @RequestMapping(value = "/downloadCSV")
        public void downloadCSV(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {

            String csvFileName = "books.csv";

            response.setContentType("text/csv");

            // creates mock data
            String headerKey = "Content-Disposition";
            String headerValue = String.format("attachment; filename=\"%s\"",
                    csvFileName);
            response.setHeader(headerKey, headerValue);

            Book book1 = new Book("Effective Java", "Java Best Practices",
                    "Joshua Bloch", "Addision-Wesley", "0321356683", "05/08/2008",
                    38);

            Book book2 = new Book("Head First Java", "Java for Beginners",
                    "Kathy Sierra & Bert Bates", "O'Reilly Media", "0321356683",
                    "02/09/2005", 30);

            Book book3 = new Book("Thinking in Java", "Java Core In-depth",
                    "Bruce Eckel", "Prentice Hall", "0131872486", "02/26/2006", 45);

            Book book4 = new Book("Java Generics and Collections",
                    "Comprehensive guide to generics and collections",
                    "Naftalin & Philip Wadler", "O'Reilly Media", "0596527756",
                    "10/24/2006", 27);

            List<Book> listBooks = Arrays.asList(book1, book2, book3, book4);

            // uses the Super CSV API to generate CSV data from the model data
            ICsvBeanWriter csvWriter = new CsvBeanWriter(response.getWriter(),
                    CsvPreference.STANDARD_PREFERENCE);

            String[] header = { "Title", "Description", "Author", "Publisher",
                    "isbn", "PublishedDate", "Price" };

            csvWriter.writeHeader(header);

            for (Book aBook : listBooks) {
                csvWriter.write(aBook, header);
            }

            csvWriter.close();
        }
    }
```

Use this as your model data class

> Book.java

```
public class Book {
    private String title;
    private String description;
    private String author;
    private String publisher;
    private String isbn;
    private String publishedDate;
    private float price;

    public Book() {
    }

    public Book(String title, String description, String author, String publisher,
            String isbn, String publishedDate, float price) {
        this.title = title;
        this.description = description;
        this.author = author;
        this.publisher = publisher;
        this.isbn = isbn;
        this.publishedDate = publishedDate;
        this.price = price;
    }

    // getters and setters...
}
```

Now run this code on server. Hit the url in browser. Your file will be downloaded without any issue. Hope this will help! :)